# Tikz, tangent between two circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create the image below

[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(0,1.25){A1}
\tkzDefPoint(0,3){A2}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){A3}
\tkzDrawCircle[very thick,color=blue,fill=green!80!black,opacity=0.6](O,A2)
\tkzDrawCircle[fill=white](O,A1)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My problem is, how Do I create the tangent line? And is there a more efficent way than mine? =)

Comment: I guess the easiest is to use a circle node `smallcirc`and refer to the `smallcirc.north`. You can either clip with the big circle or use the intersection library to get the points on the bigger circle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the tangent is horizontal, then no trig is needed and the following works.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,fill=green!20] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\path[clip] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\fill[green!30] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[thick,blue,fill=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[thick,red] (-2,1) -- (2,1) node[midway,above,black] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that this is pretty minimal, and just for generating the image you want. More sophisticated methods are available (see Jake's answer), but often I'll default to quick-and-dirty like this, because as much as I love making diagrams, time is money!

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can use `\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](A1,O)` to find a point on the tangent line passing through `A1`, and then use that new point together with `\tkzInterLC` to find the intersections between the tangent line and outer circle.

I would define the circles a bit differently:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} % centre
\tkzDefPoint(90:1){A} % defines small radius and tangent point
\tkzDefPoint(90:2){B} % defines large radius
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\tkzDrawCircle(O,B)

\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](A,O) \tkzGetPoint{Q} % find a point Q orthogonal to AO
\tkzInterLC(A,Q)(O,B) \tkzGetPoints{A'}{A''} % find intersections of a line passing through A and Q with the large circle 
\tkzDrawSegment(A',A'') % draw the tangent
\tkzDrawPoints(A,A',A'') % show the points
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

---

Of course, this can also be done with built-in TikZ mechanisms, namely the `intersections` library. Compared to a clipping approach, this has the advantage of making the end points of the tangent line available. By using the `($(<point>)!<factor>!<angle>:(<point>)$)` syntax for defining the tangent, you can use arbitrary tangent points (like `inner.37`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (inner) [draw, circle, minimum size=2cm] {}; % draw the small circle
\node (outer) [draw, circle, minimum size=4cm, name path=outer] {}; % draw the large circle, name the path for finding the intersections later
\coordinate (O) at (0,0); % name the origin
\coordinate [label=A] (A) at (inner.90)  {}; % name the tangent point on the small circle

\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox} % do not update the bounding box
\path [name path global=tangent] ($(A)!-10!90:(O)$) -- ($(A)!10!90:(O)$); % define the tangent path, make it long (20 times the radius of the small circle) to catch all intersections
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\draw [name intersections={of=outer and tangent}] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
\filldraw [fill=gray] (intersection-1) circle [radius=1pt] (intersection-2) circle [radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another useful use of `\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}`. I'm going to rewrite tkz-euclide !

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psclip{\pscustom[fillcolor=green,fillstyle=eofill]{\pscircle{3}\moveto(2,0)\pscircle{2}}}
        \psline[linecolor=red](-3,2)(3,2)
    \endpsclip
    \uput{2pt}[90](0,2){$A$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Animated version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.0+0.1}{21}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psclip{\pscustom[fillcolor=green,fillstyle=eofill]{\pscircle{3}\moveto(\n,0)\pscircle{\n}}}
        \psline[linecolor=red](-3,\n)(3,\n)
    \endpsclip
    \uput{2pt}[90](0,\n){$A$}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: no animation? :) just kidding :)

Comment: no need for clipping here. Draw a simple green circle and then a white one. That's all.

Comment: @Herbert: But I want the hole to be transparent.

Comment: ok, I missed that point

Answer (score 4):

only just for fun:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.0+0.1,\iB=0+18}{21}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psclip{\pscustom[fillcolor=green,fillstyle=eofill]{\pscircle{3}\moveto(\n,0)\pscircle{\n}}}
    \rput{\iB}(\n;\iB){%
       \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt](-5,\n)(3,\n)
       \psdot(-\n,\n)\uput{2pt}[90]{\iB}(-\n,\n){\Large A}}
    \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\uput{2pt}[90]{-\iB}(-\n,\n){\Large A}`.

Comment: the rotation of A was intended, otherwise it is no fun :-)